# Trying to have my bootstrap navabar background fade in on scroll in my wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So far I have this code:

CSS

```
.navbar {
background-color:rgba(51, 49, 50, 1);transition: background-color 2s ease 0s;
}
.navbar.hide {
background-color:rgba(51, 49, 50, 0);transition: background-color 2s ease 0s;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('hide');
} else {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('hide');
}
});
```

And this in my functions.php:

```
function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'scrollfade', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scrollfade.js');
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scrollfade' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scrollfade' );
```

I can see the script being loaded in the head section of the page source, but something still going wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing you are loading the script in the head, you should wrap the scroll event in an $(function(){}) to fire when the page is ready.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response David! Where exactly would I add that to my code?

Comment: `$(function(){ ** SCROLL CODE HERE })` this is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: hmm still not working... I have this for my code now:


$(function(){ $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('hide');
    }
}); })

Comment: where is it loaded exactly?

Comment: It's loaded in the head section, as shown in the source code:

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?ver=4.1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/js/scrollfade.js?ver=4.1.1'></script>

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this to my js file:

```
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
                $('.navbar').addClass('hide');
            } else {
                $('.navbar').removeClass('hide');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```